# Solve a initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the solution of the initial value problem $dy/dt = \sqrt{y}, y(0) = 0$, with picard-iteration. The first step is to find $y_0$, $y_1$, $y_2$,... and then a general $y_n$. When I do this is get:

$y_0 = y(0) = 0$

$y_1 = y_0 + \int^{t} _{0} \sqrt{y_0} dx = 0 + \int^{t} _{0} \sqrt{0} dx = 0+0 = 0$

$y_2 = y_0 + \int^{t} _{0} \sqrt{y_1} dx = 0 + \int^{t} _{0} \sqrt{0} dx = 0+0 = 0$

This will give the solution $y = 0$. I know that this problem has not a unique solution and that $y(t) = \frac{1}{4} t^2$ is also a solution. But how can I find this with the iterative method? What is going wrong?

Comment: At $y=0$ the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt y$ is not Lipschitz therefore the problem might have more than one solution (like in your case). Also the condition that the function $f$ be Lipschitz with respect to the second argument is only a sufficient condition for the cauchy initial value problem to have a unique solution and the Picard iterations to be a contraction mapping in some neighbourhood of $(0,0)$

Comment: Nothing goes wrong: a Picard iteration can converge at most to one solution, in this case the trivial solution.

Comment: You should start with another initial condition at $t_0$, where $y(t_0)\neq 0$. For example start with $y(2)=1$. Then you should be able to find the solution $y=\frac{1}{4} t^2$ with Picard's iteration method.

Comment: @Svetoslav: Well, I start with $y(2) = 1$. This gives $y_0 = 1$, $y_1 = y_0 + \int ^{t} _{2} \sqrt{y_0} dx = 1+(t-2) = t-1$, $y_2 = y_0 + \int ^{t} _{2} \sqrt{y_1} dx = 1++ \int ^{t} _{2} \sqrt{t-1} dx = \sqrt{t-1} (t-2) +1$, $y_3 = \sqrt{\sqrt{t-1} (t-2) +1} (t-2) +1$. This does not look like something that goes to $y(t) = \frac{1}{4} t^2$.

Comment: It should go to $\frac{1}{4}t^2$.
By the way, $y_2=y_0+\int\limits_{2}^{t}{\sqrt{s-1}ds}$